# HtmlUnit WebClient method getPage always returns the same page

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am currently working on a solution to **scrape** data from a specific website (return list of prices from a html table from a website by using css selectors). In order to do this, I decided to use the HtmlUnit library as I saw that it supports a lot of features.
After I finished the code, and tested it against the same page (with same search parameters) I thought that I was done but everything changed after starting multiple threads for multiple pages. The issue is that basically below code is always returning the same old page for all threads and I simply don't understand this behavior:

```
page = client.getPage(webPageURL); // always returns the same old page source
```

I am using the same website and I am only changing some search parameters.

These are some parts of my code:

```
final WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);  
            client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);  
            client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            client.setAjaxController(new com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
            client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            client.addRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            client.addRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            client.addRequestHeader("Expires", "0"); //
            client.getCache().clear();
            client.getCache().clearOutdated();
            client.getCache().setMaxSize(0);
            
            // enable sessions
            client.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
```

Place where the page is retrieved:

```
HtmlPage page = null;
            
            try{
                //client.closeAllWindows();
                page = client.getPage(webPageURL);
                WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse();
                pageAsString= response.getContentAsString();
```

As you noticed, I tried to play a lot with the cache (because I assume that this is the issue right?) and did some debugging by printing the page as String (pageAsString).
No matter how many times I changed the search parameters in the page url, no change whatsoever. I always got same old page.

I also tried some stuff with removing all jobs or cleaning up the page. Needless to say that none of it worked:

```
finally {
                client.getCurrentWindow().getJobManager().removeAllJobs();
                page.cleanUp();
                client.close();
                client.getCurrentWindow().getJobManager().shutdown();
                //client.closeAllWindows();
                //System.gc();
                }
```

Do you have any ideas how I messed up with the code, that I always get the same cached page?

Thank you in advance,
n23

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ not scrap

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was always using the term scrap :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a proxy issue not related to HtmlUnit (see https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/327 for more details)

Comment: Yes, the issue is not HtmlUnit related. In the end we discovered that the page is actually the issue. It must have triggered some sort of security mechanisms to prevent scrapping as after running multiple threads I could even reproduce the issue from the browser (even in incognito mode) meaning that no matter what search options I was choosing I was always getting the same page.